# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'country' of undefined

Tags: vue.js

```
<template>
<div>
    <Search v-on:onSearch="onWeather"></Search>
    <div class="locationBox">
        <h1>{{weatherData.sys.country}}</h1>
        <p>{{weatherData.name}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="weatherBox">
        <p>{{weatherData.weather.main}}℃</p>
        <p>{{weatherData.main.temp}}</p>
    </div> 
</div>
```

and script

```
onWeather(inputs) {
        alert(inputs);
        let fetchUrl = `${this.baseUrl}weather?q=${inputs}&units=metric&APPID=${this.apiKey}`;
        fetch(fetchUrl)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            return res.json();
        })
        .catch((res) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result)
            return this.onResult(result)
        })
    },
    onResult (results) {
        this.weatherData = results;
    },
```

It was clearly written according to the response value, and it is the same as the example, but an error such as the title occurs. I am very curious what the problem is. I would be very grateful if you could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing a nested object value, so you will need something like this:

```
<h1>{{weatherData.sys && weatherData.sys.country}}</h1>
```

Why the error appears you can read [here](https://hackernoon.com/accessing-nested-objects-in-javascript-f02f1bd6387f).

Comment: Thank you for attaching a good article. Thanks to that, I understood well.

Answer (score 0):

Very probable you did not initiallize the value of weatherData as and object with those values at your data(), as you are doing an async request the view is rendered before getting the value from the call. So just go to your data() and write

```
data() {
  weatherData: {
  sys: { 
     country: ' '
    }
  // all other stuff from the reponse
  }
```

And also you can write a v-if directive inside your p tags or div tavs to not be rendered till you have the response from the API so like

```
v-if="weatherData != undefined (or whaterver value you asign at your data() object)"
```